# $\frac{1}{(1+x)(y+z)}+ \frac{1}{(1+y)(x+z)}+ \frac{1}{(1+z)(y+x)} \geq \frac{27}{8}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that: $\frac{1}{(1+x)(y+z)}+ \frac{1}{(1+y)(x+z)}+ \frac{1}{(1+z)(y+x)} \geq \frac{27}{8}$

It is given that $x , y , z >0 $ and $x+y+z =1$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I am clue less. Can you tell me which inequality I should proceed with ?@SteveKass

Comment: Apply Jensen to $x\mapsto 1/(1-x^2)$.

Comment: Are you sure you got the inequality sign right? Try some numbers which are not all equal.

Comment: am-gm-qm-hm is also helpful

Comment: yes.............................@Macavity

Comment: @sani take $x + y = 10^{-10000}$ and $z = 1 - (x + y)$, then $\frac{1}{(1 + z)(x + y)} = \frac{10^{10000}}{2 - 10^{-10000}}$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Please [don't add an attempt](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites) to a question like that.

Comment: @Arnaud D I don't agree. For our site it's better to save this topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg There are guidelines to do that (see the link in my previous comment). Please follow them.

Comment: @Arnaud D.  I make steps, for to save this interesting topic, which would be better for our site. See please better this post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I've reread the post, and it says explicitly and repeatedly that one should not add an attempt as context to improve the question, which is exactly what you've done. What am I missing ?

Comment: @Arnaud D. "With few exceptions, a question should primarily remain the product of its author..." It's the  exceptions. This topic is very interesting and important for our site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the proof for the opposite inequality (which is actually true).

From AM-QM we have
$$
\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{3} \ge \left(\frac{x + y + z}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{9},
$$
so
$$
1 - \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{3} \le \frac{8}{9} 
$$
or, rearranging left-hand side,
$$
\frac{(1 - x^2) + (1 - y^2) + (1 -  z^2)}{3} \le \frac{8}{9}
$$
From HM-AM (applied to $1 - x^2$, $1 - y^2$ and $1 - z^2$) we get
$$
\frac{3}{\frac{1}{1 - x^2} + \frac{1}{1 - y^2} + \frac{1}{1 - z^2}} \le \frac{8}{9}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{1 - x^2} + \frac{1}{1 - y^2} + \frac{1}{1 - z^2} \ge \frac{27}{8}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

Since $$xy+xz+yz\leq\frac{1}{3}$$ it's
$$3(xy+xz+yz)\leq(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2,$$ by C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{(1+x)(y+z)}\geq\tfrac{9}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(1+x)(y+z)}=\tfrac{9}{2\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+xy)}\geq\frac{9}{2+\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{27}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Also, the Tangent Line method helps.

Let $x=\frac{a}{3}$, $y=\frac{b}{3}$ and $z=\frac{c}{3}.$

Thus, $a+b+c=3$ and $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(1+x)(y+z)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{9}{9-a^2}=\frac{27}{8}+9\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{9-a^2}-\frac{1}{8}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{27}{8}+\frac{9}{8}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2-1}{9-a^2}=\frac{27}{8}+\frac{9}{8}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2-1}{9-a^2}-\frac{1}{4}(a-1)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{27}{8}+\frac{9}{32}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2(a+5)}{9-a^2}\geq\frac{27}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have by the conditions that $$(x + y + z)^2 = 1$$ And that implies $$3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \ge 1 \Rightarrow -1\ge-3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \Rightarrow 8\ge 9 - 3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$$ Or
$$\frac{1}{9 - 3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} \ge \frac{1}{8}\Rightarrow \frac{9}{3 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} \ge \frac{27}{8}$$ By Titu's Lemma, $$\frac{1}{1 - x^2} + \frac{1}{1 - y^2} +\frac{1}{1 - z^2} \ge \frac{9}{3 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} \ge \frac{27}{8}$$ And $$\frac{1}{1 - x^2} + \frac{1}{1 - y^2} +\frac{1}{1 - z^2} = \frac{1}{(1 + x)(y + z)} + \frac{1}{(1 + y)(z + x)} + \frac{1}{(1 + z)(x + y)}$$ Over.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Since $$\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)''=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)''=\frac{2(1+3x^2)}{(1-x^2)^3}>0,$$ by Jensen we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(1+x)(y+z)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\geq\frac{3}{1-\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^2}=\frac{27}{8}.$$